# Getting the value from a hiddenfield on a Master page into a global variable on a Child page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I need to grab the value of a hidden field from a Master page and use the value as a global variable on a child page.

What I did was put this into the Public Partial Class:

```
public partial class frmBenefitSummaryList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //public string PlanID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["PlanID"]);
    //public string AuditID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["AuditID"]);
    //public string UID = LoginSecurity.GetUser("ID");
    public string SecLevel = (HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnSecLevel");
```

C# doesn't like this, says "`A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Page'`"

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a "global" variable, but a class member. See if making it a property works for you:

```
private HiddenField secLevelField = null;
public string SecLevel {
  get
  {
    if (secLevelField == null)
      secLevelField = (HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnSecLevel");
    if (secLevelField != null)
      return secLevelField.Value;
    else
      return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I put this on my page and it seems to accept it, but when I try to use it in an If statement (i.e. if (SecLevel = "")) it underlines SecLevel and shows an error that states: "Property or indexer 'frmBenefitSummaryList.SecLevel' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only".  I'm not trying to assign it a value, I'm trying to check its value.

Comment: `if (SecLevel == ""))` or `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SecLevel))`

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks!